# Function to check if part of a cell within a range, contains text that appears within another range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am looking for a function that I can use within CONDITIONAL FORMATTING that checks whether the contents of a range of cells, appears in another range of cells, and if so they must be highlighted using conditional formatting.

I cannot use the actual data, but here is an example:

Suppose I have the following table:

[image: pre-formula]

I want to use a Conditional Formatting formula that essentially checks whether the cells in column C contain any part of the text within Column A. The desired result would be this (I have done this manually for the purpose of the example):

[image: result]

Anyone have any ideas on a formula I can apply in Conditional Formatting to achieve this?

Many thanks!

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(C:C,"*"&A2&"*")>0`... sorry for leading down the wrong path earlier.

Comment: =1*(Sheet1!A2 = Sheet2!A2), then customize desired fill/other formatting whenever this statement is true (assuming it shall apply over the range of cells you'll select once you've complete the 'formula / format' stages.  Hit OK, and select the range over which this condition should apply (e.g. Sheet1!A2:A6).  After selecting apply (bottom right of dialogue window), recheck the equation/formula is still correct (Excel bug sometimes defaults these to the very last cell in the spreadsheet for some odd reason)!

Answer (score 1):

1. Select range "A2:A6" starting from A2 so that A2 is your active cell.
2. Insert `=MATCH("*"&A2&"*";$C$2:$C$6;0)`into the conditional format formula field.
3. The result should match your second picture.